# Creating a JAR File from a Maven Project that contains txt files

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I've managed to create a jar file from a maven project in netbeans. However, my code references txt files that are in my project, so when I try to execute my Jar File on the command prompt I get an error saying that the it could not find the txt file.

This is the current structure of my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>mavenproject3</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
   </properties>

  <build>
      <plugins>
     <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- get all project dependencies -->
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <!-- MainClass in mainfest make a executable jar -->
                <archive>
                  <manifest>
                    <mainClass>com.mycompany.mavenproject3.SSBStub</mainClass>
                  </manifest>
                </archive>

            </configuration>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>make-assembly</id>
                <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                <phase>package</phase> 
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>  
    <dependencies>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
            <artifactId>wiremock-standalone</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Is there anything I can do to the pom.xml file so that this error goes away?

Currently my txt files are in the following directory: src/text/__files/

Comment: Move that file or files into the `src/main/resources` directory and they will automatically being packaged into your resulting jar file...

Answer (score 2):

To include files into your JAR, you can use the [Maven Resource Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/index.html). It basically takes all files from a directory (by default `src/main/resources`) and puts them into your output JAR.

[From the examples page of the Resources plugin:](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html)

> By default, Maven will look for your project's resources under
>   `src/main/resources`. However, all your resources may not be in
>   `src/main/resources`. Thus, you'd have to specify those directories by
>   adding the following to your POM.

```
<project>
 ...
 <build>
   ...
   <resources>
     <resource>
       <directory>[your folder here]</directory>
     </resource>
   </resources>
   ...
 </build>
 ...
</project>
```

Comment: So, I've got my files currently in the following folder: src/test/resources/__files, so what exactly do I pass in the <directory> tag? I'm a bit unsure on how to pass the value

Comment: I'm not sure If I'm doing it correctly, I passed in the following value: src\test\resources\\__files  but im still getting an error. It still can't seem to find the file. If it helps, it seems to be looking for the file in the following directory:  C:\Users\xxx\Documents\NetBeansProjects\mavenproject3\target

Comment: Maven uses forward-slashes for file-paths

Comment: Nothing cause you are using the default directories so you don't need to configure something. This is `Convention over Configuration` paradigm.

Comment: @khmarbaise, I didn't quite understand